# Histogram graph given variance and mean value

Tags: statistics, variance

Is it possible to construct the histogram graph given the variance and the mean value of the samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do that for very specific theoretical distributions such as the Normal distribution (and then again, you would represent a *density function* rather than a real *histogram*).

For regular data, two numbers are not enough to represent hundreds or thousands of values.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $\{0\}$ and $\{0,0\}$. Both have mean and variance $0$ but different histograms.